# How to generate inputText field dynamically based on selection of p:picklist?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a scenario where I have to generate input text fields against each selection of a `<pickList>` in the same page. I am using PrimeFaces 5.2 and JSF 2.2.
Kindly advice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please elboarate. Once user chooses certain fields from source and moves it to target in pickList, do you want to render n number of inputTexts for n elements in target?

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are correct! Actually this picklist is a list of items. Based on the selection of items, i want to generate inputText Field input price for the items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here goes answer:

[image: Proof that it works]

XHTML:

```
 <p:pickList id="PojoPickList"
      value="#{editRoleAction.funcFieldDTO}" var="trnxDto"
      effect="bounce" itemValue="#{trnxDto.fieldValue}"
      itemLabel="#{trnxDto.fieldName}" showSourceControls="true"
      showTargetControls="true" converter="pickListConverter">
      <p:ajax event="transfer" update="@form"
        listener="#{editRoleAction.transactionTransferToDestination}" />
      <f:facet id="idar556" name="sourceCaption">#{msg.LBL_AVALIABLE_ROLES}     </f:facet>
    <f:facet id="idar557" name="targetCaption">#{msg.LBL_SELECTED_ROLES}</f:facet>
</p:pickList>




   <h:panelGrid id="myGrid" width="400px;">
     <p:dataTable value="#{editRoleAction.moduleTransactionList}" rendered="#{editRoleAction.moduleTransactionList.size() gt 0}" var="mainMenu">
        <p:column>
          <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Price of #{msg[mainMenu.labelId]}"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{mainMenu.kioskType}"/>
          </h:panelGrid>

        </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>

   </h:panelGrid>
```

Java:

```
  public void transactionTransferToDestination() {
        List<FunctionalityFieldDTO> destTrnx = funcFieldDTO.getTarget();
        for (FunctionalityFieldDTO dto : destTrnx) {
              moduleTransactionList.add(dto);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Apolozies for the delay Mahendran. Actually i got busy in something else. That is why i couldnt reply. Though i checked it and works perfectly as desired!!! Thank you once again